# how to download from unity asset store

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am iranian and limited for download from unity asset store.
please see these pictures:
[image] 
even i tried by kerio vpn maker but was not usage!!!!
[image]

Comment: This seems more like a question for Unity Support, rather than Stack Overflow. Consider emailing them instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their site: Unity as a company cannot do anything about the blockade, so you have to find other solutions (like asking someone else to download the free packages instead, if using proxies doesnt work)
https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/205144693--Your-country-is-blocked-due-to-the-U-S-Government-restrictions-Why-am-I-receiving-this-error-message-when-trying-to-use-Unity-

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with downloading Unity assets, you can try to do this way:
You may click on download, but it says please wait. Then, it does not change. You can go Edit/Project settings/Player in inspector pannel – other settings and undo click for Direct3D 11. Then, reopen the Unity. So, you can download your material. After complete to download, it is recommended that to click that 3D again with the same process.